# the object doesn't move to the 'right' direction

Tags: python

Hello this is my first post and I am a beginner of programming for almost three months.

Currently I am trying to cut down the problems I have to do to make the game Snake, which I am now making the movement of the snake player.

I am trying to get the 'body' block to get intact with the 'player' block, which ideally I want the code to move up, then move right to get to the 'player' block.

However, with how I wrote the code, the 'body' block does not move right after moving up to have the same y coordinate as the 'player' block.

What I think why it causes this problem is the elif where the body block keeps moving up and down to match right coordination to the player block y coordinate.

So I have tried removing elif to if, but obvious this would make the body block to move diagonally to player block, which I do not want and want only the block to move horizontally or vertically to the player block.

I have also re-organising the elif statement just to test out where the issue is, which switching between the elif's would just turn the last elif is not function, or even making the left movement to not work if my 's' down movement is before the left and right movement.

I guess I have also tried to add a new if statement above the "w" if statement as I thought that the body block wouldn't move right because the body block detects that it doesn't have the same y coordination as the player block so it prioritised moving up first. However that also didn't work out.

So what is the problem here?

```
from graphics import *
import keyboard
width = 200
height = 200

def main():
    keyW = False
    keyA = False
    keyS = False
    keyD = False
    radius = 10
    length = radius * 2

    win = GraphWin("MOVEMENTS", width, height)
    win.setBackground("black")

    player = Rectangle(Point(width-40,20), Point(width-20,40))
    player.setFill("green")
    player.setWidth(2)
    player.draw(win)

    body = Rectangle(Point(20,height-40), Point(40,height-20))
    body.setFill("green")
    body.setWidth(2)
    body.draw(win)

    while(True):
        if keyboard.is_pressed("w") and keyS==False:
            keyW = True
            keyA = False
            keyS = False
            keyD = False
        elif keyboard.is_pressed("a") and keyD==False:
            keyW = False
            keyA = True
            keyS = False
            keyD = False
        elif keyboard.is_pressed("s") and keyW==False:
            keyW = False
            keyA = False
            keyS = True
            keyD = False
        elif keyboard.is_pressed("d") and keyA==False:
            keyW = False
            keyA = False
            keyS = False
            keyD = True

        if keyW==True:
            player.move(0,-0.05)
        elif keyA==True:
            player.move(-0.05,0)
        elif keyS==True:
            player.move(0,0.05)
        elif keyD==True:
            player.move(0.05,0)

        if body.getCenter().getY() >= player.getCenter().getY(): # W
            body.move(0,-0.05)
        elif body.getCenter().getX() >= player.getCenter().getX(): # A
            body.move(-0.05,0)
        elif body.getCenter().getY() <= player.getCenter().getY(): # S
            body.move(0,0.05)
        elif body.getCenter().getX() <= player.getCenter().getX(): # D
            body.move(0.05,0)

main()
```

The result I want in this coding is:
body block (bottom left corner) to move vertically (up) until it levels with the player block (top right corner), then the body block to move horizontally (right) until it meets the player block center.

Comment: But this moves depend where the head is looking right? Not on absolute coordinates like you are doing in your moves. (If the snake is going from left to right screen, press D should make move snake to down)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue with your code as it is is that you are using `>=` and `<=` (greater than or equal to / less than or equal to) rather than `>` and `<` (strictly greater than / less than).

Based on your description, once the body is on the same `y` coordinate as the player, it should start moving left or right towards the player. On the first line of your body movement condition you have this:

```
if body.getCenter().getY() >= player.getCenter().getY(): # W
```

This is going to evaluate to `true` even if the body is on the same `y` coordinate, so the `x` movement conditions are never going to get executed.

If you instead use this:

```
if body.getCenter().getY() > player.getCenter().getY(): # W
```

the condition will no longer evaluate to true if the body is on the same `y` coordinate as the player, so it will move on to the next condition, which involves moving along horizontally.

However, I think I can suggest an easier way of doing this. In Snake usually the body blocks follow the player block exactly - if this is the intended functionality, you could simply update the body block's coordinates to the player's coordinates from the previous iteration. Just record the player's coordinates before updating them, and then set the body's coordinates to your recorded coordinates.

If you want to add more body segments that follow that, then you can set the coordinates of each one to the previous coordinates of the body segment that came before it.

Comment: I forgot to mention it in the describtion but I have tried replacing >= to > in my if/elif statement, but the problem still remains.